# Can I start a 6-month internship in Germany under a Schengen visa?

Tags: germany, student-visa, schengen, internship

I am a non-EU student currently studying in France, where I am residing with a French residence permit (titre de sejour), which in theory lets me do a 90-day internship in Germany. I have received an offer to do a 6-month internship in Germany, but the start date is too close and I am worried my visa will not be processed in time. Would it be possible to start the internship and work for up to 90 days until I receive my visa, and then finish it when/if I receive my visa within those 90 days?
If not, is it possible to sign a short-term internship contract (60 to 90 days) and then sign another, longer-term contract that starts as soon as the first one ends, and do the first one without a visa while I wait for the visa for the second internship to be processed? Thank you.

Comment: This is a question that you should ask the employer, since they will be the one that will have to pay a **very large fine** if they don't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

French residence permit (titre de sejour), DOES NOT let you do a 90-day internship in Germany or in other country than France.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

a few facts:  (talking about compulsory internships!)

- An EU residence permit acts like a tourist visa in other EU countries.
- An internship is a type of employment; a foreign permit doesn't allow you to work in Germany.
- The employer must obtain the labour office's approval for the internship (unless the internship is for less than 90 days).
- You still need a national visa for an internship (up to 90 days or more).
- The visa must be applied for at the competent German embassy (France).
- Volontary internships are considered regular employment (immigration law).

Answer (score -2):

No. The Schengen (tourist) visa does not allow you to work, and cannot be converted to a work visa. This is explicitly disallowed, and some immigration offices (like Berlin) explicitly warn you about this when you apply for a residence permit.

§5 Abs. 2 AufenthG: https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__5.html

Comment: Where would that be *explicitly* disallowed?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: A schengen tourist visa and a residence permit are completely different things.

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of the new link. This is about residence permits, the legal basis for Schengen short stay visas is completely different (it's an EU regulation), it says nothing one way or the other about working on a short-stay visa. What is indeed disallowed (in Germany and in many other places, with a few exceptions) is to transition from a short-stay visa to a long-stay residence permit but that's not the question at hand (the OP has already applied for a visa).